# Avoid resizing block-level elements, when the browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

The example below displays left and right side bars and a content bar using `<div>`s.

```css
#content {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#left {
    float: left;
    width:  120px;
}

#right {
    float: right;
    width:  120px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="border: 3px solid black;">
    <div id="left" style="border: 2px solid #008000;">Left</div>
    <div id="right" style="border: 2px solid #008000;">Right</div>

    <div id="content">
        <table style="width: 100%; height: 500px; border: 2px solid #F00;" rules="all">
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the browser window is resized, the table in the content `<div>` is also resized that should not happen. Anyway, resizing the browser window should not affect the contents it displays.

How to avoid resizing the content bar so that only scroll bars appear on the browser window, when it is resized (the contents should remain the same as it is displayed on page load)?

<sub>I tried giving `display: inline-block` to `content` but that did not work properly.</sub>

Comment: use fixed width if you dont want content to resize

Answer (score 1):

Block elements are 100% width of the viewport by default.

If you don't want them changing size, assign a `width:` `min-width:` or `max-width:` to your own liking.

Comment: Adding `display: inline-block; min-width: 500px;` to the `content` CSS class causes the content bar to lower the left and right side bars, when contents does not fit while resizing the window which is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen a request like this before.

1. Whatever the container on page load is the container and then scroll the view port if the window is resized.

### DEMO:http://jsbin.com/jemeyo/1/

Edit: http://jsbin.com/jemeyo/1/edit

---

This requires getting the width and then adding with a script, in this case, I'm using jQuery.

https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual to start

### jQuery:

```
/*! Copyright 2012, Ben Lin (http://dreamerslab.com/)
 * Licensed under the MIT License (LICENSE.txt).
 * https://github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.actual
 * Version: 1.0.16
 *
 * Requires: jQuery >= 1.2.3
 */
(function(a){a.fn.addBack=a.fn.addBack||a.fn.andSelf;
a.fn.extend({actual:function(b,l){if(!this[b]){throw'$.actual => The jQuery method "'+b+'" you called does not exist';}var f={absolute:false,clone:false,includeMargin:false};
var i=a.extend(f,l);var e=this.eq(0);var h,j;if(i.clone===true){h=function(){var m="position: absolute !important; top: -1000 !important; ";e=e.clone().attr("style",m).appendTo("body");
};j=function(){e.remove();};}else{var g=[];var d="";var c;h=function(){c=e.parents().addBack().filter(":hidden");d+="visibility: hidden !important; display: block !important; ";
if(i.absolute===true){d+="position: absolute !important; ";}c.each(function(){var m=a(this);var n=m.attr("style");g.push(n);m.attr("style",n?n+";"+d:d);
});};j=function(){c.each(function(m){var o=a(this);var n=g[m];if(n===undefined){o.removeAttr("style");}else{o.attr("style",n);}});};}h();var k=/(outer)/.test(b)?e[b](i.includeMargin):e[b]();
j();return k;}});})(jQuery);


 $(window).on('load', function() {

    var containerwidth = $('#container').actual('width');

    $('#container').css('width', (containerwidth) + 'px');


 });
```

### CSS added so it doesn't go very, very wide (my preference) and it centers:

```
#container {max-width:1200px;margin:0 auto;}
```

### HTML (SEE OP)

Note: even if the viewport is really small, it will fix it, I suggest wrapping this in a resize and load with a window width of your choice so that it kicks in above certain sizes. It may be very strange on viewport orientation changes as that is not loading so it won't auto adjust. Very odd request, but anyway, here it is.